# exposing an object in angularjs directive scope, can't access properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So, I have the following relatively simple Angularjs directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              site: '@',
              index: '@'
          },
          template: '<div>{{site}}</div>',
          replace: true,

      }
  });
```

And here is where I call the directive in HTML

```
<div id="eventGraphic" class="span12">
    <my-directive ng-repeat="site in IEvent.sites" site="{{site}}" index="{{$index}}"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Which, given that each `site` is an object, produces this output (copied from browser)

```
{"name":"Hurlburt","_id":"5148bb6b79353be406000005","enclaves":[]}
{"name":"Walker Center","_id":"5148cca5436905781a000005","enclaves":[]}
{"name":"test1","_id":"5148ce94436905781a000006","enclaves":[]}
{"name":"JDIF","_id":"5148cf37436905781a000007","enclaves":[]}
```

However, if I change the template in the directive to

```
 template: '<div>{{site.name}}</div>',
```

it does not produce any output.  This seems like a fairly straightforward use case, any ideas what I could be doing wrong?  The desired output would be just the `name` field in each object.

Comment: Is your directive going to allow the user to change the `site` data, or will it be creating its own properties on the scope?  If not, then you probably don't need an isolate scope -- you can save some memory and have the directive use the scope that ng-repeat creates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `'='` to map the object. `'@'` implies you're just passing a string value to the new scope.

```js
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              site: '=', //two-way binding
              index: '@' //just passing an attribute as a string.
          },
          template: '<div>{{site}}</div>',
          replace: true,

      }
  });
```

Then in your markup, don't use a binding in the attribute, just pass the expression:

```html
<div id="eventGraphic" class="span12">
    <!-- below, site="site" is passing the expression (site) to
         the two way binding for your directive's scope,
         whereas index="{{$index}}" is actually evaluating the expression
         ($index) and passing it as a string to the index attribute,
         which is being put directly into the directive's scope as a string -->
    <my-directive ng-repeat="site in IEvent.sites" 
            site="site" 
            index="{{$index}}"></my-directive>
</div>
```